# Java ssh (jsch) output to UI instead of console

Tags: java, ajax, jsch

I have the following code which uses JSch to run commands on remote server and its working fine when called through the main method.

```
public static void runCommand(String user, String password, String host, String command,String yesorno ) {

    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + host);
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setPty(true);
        channel.connect();
        out.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
        out.flush();
        OutputStream out1 = channel.getOutputStream();


        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0) break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                if(new String(tmp,0,i).toLowerCase().contains("y/n"))
                {

                    out1.write((yesorno + "\n").getBytes());
                    out1.flush();

                }
                else if(new String(tmp,0,i).contains("password"))
                {
                    out1.write((password + "\n").getBytes());
                    out1.flush();

                }



            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Exit status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }

        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (JSchException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Now I want to print the command execution trace as it happens but I want it in my interface of my webpage from where I pass the command to this java method. How can I achieve this. I have been searching the Internet for last 2 days without any good answers. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: We need some information about your UI. Do you have a UI set up already?

Comment: No I have just started but have no idea about sending data dynamically to the front end. I mean I can easily let the command execute and store it in a Buffered Stream object and the print it in the UI . But the requirement is to display the data as it is being executed.

Comment: I would take a look at Restful web services which you can use to trigger your method from the front end. Then you can return the response to the front end. I would suggest looking into Spring as it takes away a lot of the boilerplate stuff https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ or if you want to do it manually try https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_quick_guide.htm

Comment: I am using Restful web service , I am providing the data to the rest class like host name and password, and then calling the service class which have the code written above. The question is How will I send the data back to the front end while the service class method is still running.

Comment: Basically need some sort of Observer to observe changes as they are occuring. Look into the observer pattern: http://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern and watch objects for changes and push them out to the front end with a scheduled task. You'll need to change your code slightly by adding some sort of SCPReponse object to hold responses. Personally for things like this I find https://stomp.github.io/ useful but it might be a bit more fiddly

Comment: maybe if you can provide me some code reference it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to use web socket for this and use the whole function inside an onmessage block in Java. I used Json to provide the command and require field from frontend and parsed and used it in the function which then prints the output in the UI